# Android Mux mp4a and mp4

Tags: java, android, mp4

I extracted a MPEG-DASH xml and i downloaded media urls manually and i have a mp4 video file and Audio file has saved separately into a mp4a file.
I want to merge this audio and video file into a single mp4 file.
I tried with MediaMuxer, But MediaExtractor does not know mp4a file.

I extracted files meta data info like codec, and other details in below.

Audio file meta data info

```
MDItemAudioBitRate                = 48
kMDItemAudioChannelCount           = 1
kMDItemCodecs                      = (
    AAC
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate         = 2018-08-03 09:41:01 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate     = 2018-08-03 09:41:01 +0000
kMDItemContentType                 = "public.mpeg-4"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
    "public.mpeg-4",
    "public.item",
    "public.movie",
    "public.audiovisual-content",
    "public.mpeg-4",
    "public.data",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                   = 2018-08-03 09:41:01 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking           = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                 = "1533200401950_a.mp4"
kMDItemDurationSeconds             = 1129.732
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate         = 2018-08-03 09:41:01 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate              = 2018-08-03 09:41:01 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode               = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags               = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon             = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                 = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden         = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery              = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                     = 0
kMDItemFSName                      = "1533200401950_a.mp4"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                 = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID              = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID               = 501
kMDItemFSSize                      = 7068402
kMDItemFSTypeCode                  = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking     = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemKind                        = "MPEG-4 movie"
kMDItemLastUsedDate                = 2018-08-03 11:18:56 +0000
kMDItemLastUsedDate_Ranking        = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemLogicalSize                 = 7068402
kMDItemMediaTypes                  = (
    Sound
)
kMDItemPhysicalSize                = 7069696
kMDItemStreamable                  = 0
kMDItemTotalBitRate                = 48
kMDItemUseCount                    = 7
kMDItemUsedDates                   = (
    "2018-08-02 19:30:00 +0000"
)
```

Video meta data info :

```
kMDItemCodecs                      = (
    "H.264"
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate         = 2018-08-03 11:06:58 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate     = 2018-08-03 11:07:02 +0000
kMDItemContentType                 = "public.mpeg-4"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
    "public.mpeg-4",
    "public.item",
    "public.movie",
    "public.audiovisual-content",
    "public.mpeg-4",
    "public.data",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                   = 2018-08-03 11:06:58 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking           = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                 = "1533200401950_v.mp4"
kMDItemDurationSeconds             = 1129.441
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate         = 2018-08-03 11:07:02 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate              = 2018-08-03 11:06:58 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode               = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags               = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon             = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                 = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden         = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery              = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                     = 0
kMDItemFSName                      = "1533200401950_v.mp4"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                 = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID              = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID               = 501
kMDItemFSSize                      = 107974918
kMDItemFSTypeCode                  = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking     = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemKind                        = "MPEG-4 movie"
kMDItemLastUsedDate                = 2018-08-03 11:07:06 +0000
kMDItemLastUsedDate_Ranking        = 2018-08-03 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemLogicalSize                 = 107974918
kMDItemMediaTypes                  = (
    Video
)
kMDItemPhysicalSize                = 117506048
kMDItemPixelHeight                 = 704
kMDItemPixelWidth                  = 396
kMDItemStreamable                  = 0
kMDItemTotalBitRate                = 762
kMDItemUseCount                    = 1
kMDItemUsedDates                   = (
    "2018-08-02 19:30:00 +0000"
)
kMDItemVideoBitRate                = 762
```

Please advice